# Setting attribute value of object inside array using _.find

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I am pretty sure there is a better way of doing this. In the code below, I am trying to set the value of item object inside selected_items array. I've discovered that using '=' instead of '==' returned an altered version of the found object (a behavior that I found useful in other parts of my code).

Is this a good idea? I would really like to know a cleaner way of doing this using lodash.

```
$scope.increase_item_quantity = function(item_pk, addition){
    if($scope.is_item_selected()){
        var item_quantity = $scope.get_item_quantity();
        if(!(item_quantity < 1 && addition == -1)){
            console.log('adding...')
            $scope.selected_items = _.result(_.find($scope.selected_items, function(item) {
                  return item.quantity = addition;
                }), 'quantity');
        }
    }
}
```

Via the method above, I am trying to set the quantity of the item with a particular id.

Comment: This looks like a horrible maintenance problem because it doesn't make sense reading it. Why don't you simply loop over original array and change the values?

Comment: can you provide a desired input and a desired output?

Comment: Now you changed the whole question. That is not right! Stop making the question a moving target and invalidating answers that were based on what you originally had.

Comment: Yes, and the question no longer even makes sense...you talk about `=` vs. `==` but now you changed it to `+=`...once again, you don't need lodash for what you're doing. Just use plain JS.

Comment: Am voting to close now that none of the question makes sense. Description and code don't match

Comment: I don't really understand why you guys make a big fuzz out of this. What I am trying to say is "can I set (or reassign or change) a property value of an object (inside array) using _.find? ". I just need a yes or no answer!!

Answer (score 3):

Simple vanilla js

```
$scope.selected_items.forEach(function(item){
     item.quantity = new_quantity;
});
```

Comment: Yes. You don't need lodash for this...it just complicates things.